# facing an error code **PayPal error (10755): An error (10755) occurred while processing your PayPal payment

Tags: paypal, checkout

I am facing an error code **PayPal error (10755): An error (10755) occurred while processing your PayPal payment. Please contact the store owner for assistance.** My website doesn't have any type of coupons but still this error is coming. Can anyone help me solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

10755 occurs due to an unsupported currency, as detailed in the legacy [API Error Codes](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/nvp-soap-api/errors/)

If you need further help for some reason, log and include the entire API request text and the entire API response text in your question

The request text should include the currency code you are using, and the response text should include a Correlation Id or PayPal-Debug-Id